# Account not linked with data.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, status-bydesign, data-explorer, linked-accounts, association-bonus

I created an account at data.stackexchange, but it never got linked with my SO account. For any other SE site I create an account in it will say that my account is already linked with other SE sites (mostly SO, I think), and reward about 100 pts.

Is this meant to be?

My recently created profile is: https://data.stackexchange.com/users/6387

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is by-design, data.stackexchange.com isn't tied to the other sites in terms of user accounts...this *may* change later, but there's no account relation at the moment.