# Accounts not linked across some communities

Tags: support, login, linked-accounts

I am a member of many communities, including Stack Overflow, [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour), [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/tour), and others. My settings show 20 communities.

But it seems not all my communities are linked. I can see them all in the "meta selector". When switching to some communities from the selector, I am logged in, others I need to re-login. I login to all communities using the same userid/password. It clearly knows "it's me" as my communities and points always  show on meta selector for all sites, if I am logged into the present site. This makes no sense.

I came across this rather old question: "[Account not linked with data.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99729/864667)" which suggests at the time (2011), not all communities are linked, "by (poor?) design" / intent.

Is this still the case? How do we know which are linked and which are not? Why would related communities not be linked and require logging in? Those I listed: Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, and DevOps are all closely related, active users posting in the most appropriate community are likely to be members of most or all of those and switch regularly.

Finding yourself continuously having to login (if you've logged off) is most inconvenient.

Is there something wrong with my account? Do I have to synchronize my profile/settings? How? It seems to recognize my Email settings across all communities. This response to [asking to separate accounts suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300874/864667) accounts would auto-merge. Did that fail?

If nothing is wrong with my account, is there a roadmap to link at least clearly related communities? When? If not, why is this "by design"? Is there a reference document/page which shows which communities are linked?

**Additional Info:**
Having logged out and cleared all the cookies (I also tried the following in private browsing mode), seems there is a distinct asymmetry going on.
Logging into S/O also connects me to ServerFault, SuperUser, AskUbuntu, but not any of the other communities listed under Network Profile | Accounts. But if I log into StackExchange or says, DevOps, I find myself logged into all 20 sites.

In both scenarios, when I log out, I am warned, "Clicking `Log out` will log you out of the following domains on this device: "askubuntu.com, mathoverflow.net, serverfault.com, stackapps.com, stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com, superuser.com". I am not a member of 2 of those. It does however log me out of all sites I was logged into (either scenario).

I also confirmed this is the case both on my PC and Android device, both in Chrome and FF.

I reviewed @rene's answers and don't believe it explains this.

Comment: There are [19 accouts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1307921?accountid=294314) for you, it looks like you just added Meta.SE today so that makes 20 and that matches what I see on your profile. If you need to login on sites with a non *.stackexchange.com domain you might have disabled third-party cookies in your browser or use Safari that is broken by design. If you believe you have way more then 20 userprofiles, please  share some links to them that are not in the SEDE list I offered.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312956/158100

Comment: Added additional info regarding logging in; don't believe links help clarify.

Comment: Is this a recent happening or has happened for a long time? Please do state the chrome and FF version being used here.

Comment: On the Desktop, it's FF 81.0.1 and Chrome 85 (Updates managed by Enterprise). on Android, it's FF 68.11 and Chrome 86. Cookeies, cache, cleared on all. I noticed the issue w/DevOps group a while ago but never dawned on me to investigate until recently. Perhaps it happened on others too, but rarely post to them. Regardless, it's weird,especially that's it's asymmetric.

Comment: Can you start a private mode browser session, open the developer console, enable network logging, login on Stack Overflow and find the POST call to `/users/login/universal/request`, inspect its content. Verify you see GET requests to `/users/login/universal.gif?authToken=` and that it returns cookies for each Host found in that POST response. Rinse repeat but  replace the step Login to Stack Overflow to an StackExchange.com site. Record differences (don't share the nonce and token  nor the content of the cookies publicly though as it might allow others to do things on your behalf).